# Show only 3 first characters - PHP script needed

Tags: php

I'm looking php script or atleast function, wicth transform last characters to * symbols.
Something like:

```
$name = "Hamingway";
```

After function output would look like:

Ham******

Or if $name is only 3 characters long or less, It would output only ***

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp

Comment: Why this post has so many negative votes?! Just because it's written in some woody English? Totally unfair!

Answer (score 1):

**Please read the PHP basics!**

Short script for you:

```
<?php
$name = "Hamingway";
echo (strlen($name) > 3) ? substr($name, 0, 3) . str_repeat('*', strlen($name) - 3) : str_repeat('*', strlen($name));
?>
```